# Difference between Usenet and forums in terms of servers?

Tags: networking, webserver, administrator, usenet, forum

I tried to understand the true difference between Usenet and regular forums in termas of servers adminstrations and organizing but with no avail.

This is qutoed from Wikipedia "*absence of a central server and dedicated administrator. Usenet is distributed among a large, constantly changing conglomeration of servers that store and forward messages to one another in so-called news feeds*"

Two things are here:

1- "*Absence of Central Server*". I would say that's also the case in large forums. There are no one central server, but a group of servers.

2- "*No dedicated Admin*". How is this possible? I mean there must be someone/group who takes care of the whole thing. Especially that files are being hosted on these servers and not on users PCs. I mean in case of torrents, "No admin" would be acceptable as files are hosted on users PCs. But not in our case here.

**Question: What is the true difference in terms of servers organizing, in a liitle bit of details?**

Comment: "No dedicated Admin" usenet has distributed admins, 1 for each distrubuted server ;) Usenet is essentially peer to peer between servers, with server admins deciding where to get externals feeds from.

Comment: Some newsgroups are moderated, so controlled by a group of moderators. See [Moderated Newsgroups FAQ](http://pages.swcp.com/~dmckeon/mod-faq.html)

Comment: See also [How Does Usenet Work?](http://www.harley.com/usenet/usenet-tutorial/how-does-usenet-work.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplistic explanation.

**Usenet** is like a distributed bulletin board system. Messages are stored in **news servers** worldwide, and each server hosts several **newsgroups**, which are discussion groups devoted to a special topic. Users post and fetch messages to newsgroups using **news readers**. Messages are exchanged between users and news servers - and distributed from a news server to another - via the **NNTP** protocol.

Usenet has no centralized authority just like the World Wide Web has no centralized authority; single webservers and websites may be administered by different organizations, but nobody controls the Web as a whole. Just like the Web is the worldwide network of webservers accessed via HTTP/HTTPS, Usenet is the worldwide network of news servers accessed via NNTP.

On the other hand, a forum is an online discussion site implemented on a specific webserver using a specific software ([see here for a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software)). As such, each forum has its own admins and users.